# Typescript strict arrays and dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, typescript

I'm trying to define a dictionary-like type.  I can't figure out how to get the Typescript compiler to strictly check the key type.

```
var map: {[hello:number]: string} = {}
// I get the same results if I declare: var map: string[] = []

map[1.1] = "hello";
map[1.1] = 1.1;                 // error (as expected)
map["hello"] = "hello";         // missing error on key
map["hello"] = 1.1;             // missing error on key
var s2: string = map[1.1];
var i2: number = map[1.1];      // error (as expected)
var s1: string = map["hello"];  // missing error on key
var i1: number = map["hello"];  // missing error on key
```

I get the same results with Typescript 1.5.3 and 1.6.0-beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to get the Typescript compiler to strictly check the key type.

`string` indexing is always allowed in TypeScript. This is to mimic the fact that even though you say that you are indexing by a `number` *you are actually indexing by a `string`* (`foo[1]` is same as `foo['1']`)

However you can specify a restriction on `string` as well as `number`. But note that *it must be consistent with `number` because after all `number` is going to get converted to a string at runtime anyways*. This removes two of the mentioned error cases:

```
var map: {
    [key: number]: string;
    [key: string]: string;
} = {};
// I get the same results if I declare: var map: string[] = []

map[1.1] = "hello";
map[1.1] = 1.1;                 // error (as expected)
map["hello"] = "hello";         // missing error on key
map["hello"] = 1.1;             // error
var s2: string = map[1.1];
var i2: number = map[1.1];      // error (as expected)
var s1: string = map["hello"];  // missing error on key
var i1: number = map["hello"];  // error
```

Comment: Hmm, it's too bad Typescript doesn't let you restrict the key (I tried restricting it to `string` and that didn't really work either -- it looks like number keys are implicitly converted to strings).

Answer (score -1):

I made my own Dictionary type, good for dropdowns (I am using kendo dropdowns from kendo UI):

type Dictionary = Array< { key: string, value: string } >;

Comment: Lookup-by-key operations will be O(N) here, right?  I want the underlying data structure to be a Javascript native hashtable so that lookup is O(1).

Comment: Ah no, it's just simple array with objects. For real dictionary we need a solution like above.